# ¿Obtener el atributo de un boton con jQuery y Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".eliminar").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    //alert(id);
    $(this).closest('.holder-cesta').remove();

    //Esta parte no me funciona.
    $.post('./php/carro_compra/eliminar.php', {
      Id: id
    }, function(a) {
      if (a == '0') {
        location.href = "./cesta";
      }
    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="holder-cesta">
  <h4>Product 1</h4>
  <button class="eliminar" data-id="1">Delete</button>
</div>

<div class="holder-cesta">
  <h4>Product 3</h4>
  <button class="eliminar" data-id="3">Delete</button>
</div>

<div class="holder-cesta">
  <h4>Product 2</h4>
  <button class="eliminar" data-id="2">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Estoy creando el `boton` de eliminar los productos de la cesta. Cada producto añadido tendra un `boton` de eliminar.

Los resultados del carro de la compra la guardo en una sesión llamado `$_SESSION['carrito'];`

Aquí va el código donde llamo los productos y su botón de eliminar:

```
<?php
    //Array carrito de compras.
    $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
    $total = 0;                                     

    for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
?>

      <div class="holder-cesta">
         <h4><?php echo $data[$i]['Titulo']; ?></h4>    
         <button class="eliminar" data-id="<?php echo $data[$i]['Id']; ?>">Eliminar</button>    
      </div>
<?php
     }
?>
```

`data-id` obtengo el `id` de producto.

Veamos el codigo jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".eliminar").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        //Obtengo el id desde nuestro boton.
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');       

        //Mi alert lanza correctamente el id associado.
        //alert(id);
        $(this).closest('.holder-cesta').remove();//Remueve correctamente           
        //AJAX
        //Aqui viene mi problema,no obtengo var id en $.post y tampoco parece que vaya a la url eliminar.php
        $.post('./php/carro_compra/eliminar.php', {
            Id:id
        },function(a) {
            if (a=='0') {
                location.href="./cesta";
            }
        });


    });
});
```

si hago un `var_dump($_POST['Id']);` en mi archivo eliminar.php , realmente no ace nada dicha función, si modifico un poco el ajax, me manda un NULL.

El `jQuery` funciona bien, ya que me lanza correctamente el alert y tambien me elimina el div .holder-cesta, pero el problema es como si nunca va a la url de `$.post` donde quiero actuailzar el array mediante el `Id` de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($arreglo[$i]['Id']!= $_POST['Id']) {

}
```

Adjunto tambien el archivo eliminar.php con el que quiero actualizar mi carrito de compras al eliminar un producto:

```
  <?php
//Session start
session_start();
//Get shoping cart data.
$arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];

for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++) { 
    //Logica, si id del articulo es diferente a la variable obtenido por Ajax.
    if ($arreglo[$i]['Id']!= $_POST['Id']) {

        $datosnuevos[] = ['Id' => $arreglo[$i]['Id'], 'Titulo' =>$arreglo[$i]['Titulo'], 'Precio' => $arreglo[$i]['Precio'], 'Icon' => $arreglo[$i]['Icon'], 'Cantidad' => $arreglo[$i]['Cantidad'] ];
    }
}

if (isset($datosnuevos)) {
    //Modifico la sesion, dejando el resto de articulos comprados.
    $_SESSION['carrito'] = $datosnuevos;
    //Modificamos el valor del carro.
    $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
    $value_carrito = count($data);
    $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;
    //Asi tambien se recarga la página con los datos actualizado
    echo "0";

} else {
    unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
    unset($_SESSION['compras']);
    echo "0";
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está el código de eliminar.php? El JavaScript funciona bien, no hay error en la llamada AJAX, si hay un error estará en eliminar.php que no has compartido en tu pregunta.

Comment: Te he añadido como tengo compuesto el codigo eliminar.php, no veo tampoco nada malo, asi a simple vista, el alert, me escoge correctemante el id.

Comment: agregue una respuesta para que actualices tu código saludos.

Answer (score 3):

si el contenido del carrito se agrega por ajax y jquery no te va a servir:

```
 $(".eliminar").click(function(e) {
```

Cambialo por :

```
 $(document).on("click",'.eliminar', function (event, xhr, settings) {
```

lo que te esta pasando es que tienes un problema de Bind del DOM y un nuevo elemento.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné Francisco, el fallo lo tenía en la url del `AJAX`, nunca iba al archivo `PHP`, modifique `./php/carro_compra/eliminar.php` por `/php/carro_compra/eliminar.php`. Con ese cambio me funciona correctamente.

Comment: @D.Bulten perfecto

Comment: te sugiero usar la delegación de funciones cuando trabajas con ajax.

Comment: avisa como te va ??

Comment: Francisco, esta semana lo pruebo y te comento. Que tengo el proyecto un poco de lado. Un saludo

Comment: también funciono tu ejemplo. Me puedes explicar por qué es mejor, ya que el de mi ejemplo también funciona. En `jQuery` `Ajax` me pierdo un poco. Te dejo mis +1

Comment: @D.Bulten lo que pasa es que cuando haces esto `$(".eliminar").click` estas utilizando una funciona anonima establecida en la carga del DOM original y no toma en consideración algunos elementos del DOM que has agregado mediante AJAX, la opcion que te agregue  `$(document).on("click",'.eliminar',` es mas detallista, ya que maneja propiedades del ajax y tambien busca elementos que no estaban en el DOM Original... es por eso que recomiendo esta manera de manejar la las funciones anonimas, mejora tu código.

Answer (score 2):

`cart.php`

```
//Carro de la compra

//Si esta definida la ID obtenido por URL
if (isset($_GET['articulo'])) {

    $id_tutorial = $_GET['articulo'];//Obtenemos el ID del tutorial añadido, para poder acer comprobaciones a mostrar otros resultados.

    //Si esta definido la sesion carro -> es decir si ay algun articulo comprado
    if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {

        $arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];
        $encontro = false;      

        for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++) { 

            if ($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_GET['articulo']) {
                $encontro = true;               
            }
        }

        if ($encontro == false) {


            $titulo = "";
            $precio = 0;
            $precioUSD = 0;
            $icon = "";

            $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT titulo,precio,icon,id_autor FROM tutoriales WHERE page=? and status=1");
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['articulo']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                $stmt->bind_result($titulo,$precio,$icon,$id_autor);
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                    //Sentencia prepare -> autor proyecto
                    $stmtN = $c->prepare("SELECT autor FROM autor WHERE id_autor=?");           
                    $stmtN->bind_param("i", $id_autor);         
                    $stmtN->execute();          
                    $stmtN->bind_result($autor);            
                    $stmtN->fetch();            
                    $stmtN->close();

                    $datosnuevos = array('Id' => $_GET['articulo'], 'Titulo' => $titulo, 'Precio' => $precio, 'Icon' => $icon, 'Cantidad' => 1 );

                    /*
                        #Si se utiliza array_push() para añadir un solo elemento al array, es mejor utilizar $array[] = ya que de esta forma no existe la sobrecarga de llamar a una función. 
                    */

                    //array_push($arreglo, $datosnuevos); 
                    $arreglo[] = $datosnuevos;
                    $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;

                    $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                    $value_carrito = count($data);
                    $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;

                } $stmt->close();


            } else {
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }   

    } else { //Caso falso añadimos primer articulo al carro

        $titulo = "";
        $precio = 0;
        $precioUSD = 0;
        $icon = "";

        $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT titulo,precio,icon,id_autor FROM tutoriales WHERE page=? and status=1");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['articulo']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($titulo,$precio,$icon,$id_autor);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                //Sentencia prepare -> autor proyecto
                $stmtN = $c->prepare("SELECT autor FROM autor WHERE id_autor=?");           
                $stmtN->bind_param("i", $id_autor);         
                $stmtN->execute();          
                $stmtN->bind_result($autor);            
                $stmtN->fetch();            
                $stmtN->close();

            } $stmt->close();

        } else {
            $stmt->close();
        }       

            $arreglo[] = array('Id' => $_GET['articulo'], 'Titulo' => $titulo, 'Precio' => $precio, 'Icon' => $icon, 'Cantidad' => 1 );

            $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;

            $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
            $value_carrito = count($data);
            $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;

            //echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";


    }

}
```

`cesta.php` Aqui llamo al carrito, y donde elimino los articulos añadidos

```
<?php //Mostramos resultados carro de la compra.

    //Resetemos el total.
    $total = 0;

    //Si esta definido la sesión.
    if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {              

        //Array con datos carrito.
        $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
        $total = 0;                                     

        //Recorremos todo el array, para salida de datos.
        for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
?>

            <div class="holder-cesta">
                <h4><?php echo $data[$i]['Titulo']; ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $data[$i]['Precio']; ?></p>
                <?php                   
                $total = ($data[$i]['Cantidad'] * $data[$i]['Precio']) + $total;
                ?>

                <button class="eliminar" data-id="<?php echo $data[$i]['Id']; ?>">Eliminar</button>

            </div>

<?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 articulos";
    } unset($arreglo);
?>
```

El archivo `eliminar.php`

```
<?php
//Session start
session_start();
//Get shoping cart data.
$arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];

//Reset.
$arr[] ='';


var_dump($arreglo);

//var_dump($_POST['Id']);

for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++) { 

    if ($arreglo[$i]['Id']!= $_POST['Id']) {

        //$datosnuevos = ['Id' => $arreglo[$i]['Id'], 'Titulo' =>$arreglo[$i]['Titulo'], 'Precio' => $arreglo[$i]['Precio'], 'Icon' => $arreglo[$i]['Icon'], 'Cantidad' => $arreglo[$i]['Cantidad'] ];
        $arr[] =$arreglo[$i]
    }
}

if (isset($arr)) {

    $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arr;

    $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
    $value_carrito = count($data);
    $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;

} else {
    unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
    unset($_SESSION['compras']);
    echo "0";
}
?>
```

Comment: Lo e modificado y probado, pero sigue igual, aunque borre todo del arhivo eliminar y simplemente hago un echo'Hola mundo'; tampoco imprime. Y el archivo esta vinculo correctamente, que ya lo e revisado, modificado el nombre, etc, todo lo que a uno se le ocurra! Pero no logro obtener resultados desde eliminar.php. Existe algun otro metodo, si alguien pudiero poner otro ejemplo tambien valido a lo que busco?

Comment: Has probado a forzar que te devuelva el  0?. En caso de que la cesta no esté vacia, no puede devolver el script de reload, deberías ponerlo en el codigo

Comment: Vale, eliminare el reload, en caso de actualizar la cesta. Al principio si que me funcionabe si solamente habia un articulo en mi cesta y le deba a eliminar, me funcionaba correctamente el codigo, pero en caso de tener mas de un producto, ya no entraba en la logica != $_POST. Aro probando ya ni entra en el caso 0 XD

Comment: Si esfuerzo el 0, funciona, me modifica todo correctamente y me recarga la funciona ajax function(a). simplemente solo dejo esto en eliminar.php:
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
unset($_SESSION['compras']);
echo "0";

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta, con lo que deberias tener mas o menos en tus ficheros,tanto en eliminar.php, como en el carrito

Comment: He editado tu prejuntada a como tenia el codigo, pero esta bajo revision. Aunque ahora mismo lo tengo en funcionamiento correctamente, lo e subido a mi servidor, modifico en mi ejemplo como he dejado el archivo eliminar.php de esta manera funciona, el unico problema que tengo aro esque debo actualizar manualmente para ver el resultado :(, como podria refrescar dichos datos eliminados?¿. Digamos si tengo elimino el jquery me elimnado todo pero asta que no ago manual un refresh no se modifica la session.

Comment: Ya lo tengo solucionado, muchas gracias por la coloboración. En mi ejemplo he modificado el archivo eliminar.php, que es donde tenia el fallo, de la forma que lo e dejado, me esta funcionado correctamente :)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, podría ser porque eliminas antes de hacer lo que quieres? 
Primero eliminas :

```
$(this).closest('.holder-cesta').remove();//Remueve correctamente
```

y luego quieres consultar el id : `Id:id` pero claro, ya no existe, prueba en primero hacer todo lo que quieres y finalmente eliminar lo que quieras:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".eliminar").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        //Obtengo el id desde nuestro boton.
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');       

        //Mi alert lanza correctamente el id associado.
        //alert(id);         
        //AJAX
        //Aqui viene mi problema,no obtengo var id en $.post y tampoco parece que vaya a la url eliminar.php
        $.post('./php/carro_compra/eliminar.php', {
            Id:id
        },function(a) {
            if (a=='0') {
                location.href="./cesta";
            }
        });
 $(this).closest('.holder-cesta').remove();//Remueve correctamente 

    });
});
```

Comment: vale, voy a probar aver si elimino la linea de .remove(); aver si me escoge el documento de Ajax.

Comment: Lo e probado, pero me sigue haciendo lo mismo, si luego lo pienso, realmente obtengo antes que remuevo el div, var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); con el id,